# Getting the minimum size of a UIView based on its constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have created a custom nib and added it to my view hierarchy. The view separates to subviews using a constraint which is greater than or equal to, in other words, giving the view a minimum size to work with.

Is it possible to get the minimum size of a UIView from the constraints system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`UIView` has a method `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` to return the smallest size (or largest size) for a view.

`CGSize smallestViewSize = [view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];`

The `UIView` method `intrinsicContentSize` returns the most desired size. This size may be somewhat in the middle of the two sizes returned before.

Prior to iOS6, you would call `sizeThatFits:` to get a fitting size that may be smaller than the size passed in or was by default the bounds of the receiver.